# how to set style sheet for custom shaped Qpushbutton

Tags: c++, qt

I have inherited Qpushbutton to make it circular shape, if I set background in paintevent of this class it works fine but I want to set different image for each instant of this class so I tried setting it by seticon and setstylesheet but it does not work. What could be the reason. please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

this is my code.

```
CirclularButton::CirclularButton(QWidget *parent):QPushButton(parent)
{
}

void CirclularButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    p.drawEllipse(0, 0, 50, 50);
}

and in another class where I am using it,

 CirclularButton *cir = new CirclularButton(this);
    cir->setGeometry(50,50,50,50);
    cir->setStyleSheet("border:1px solid red");
```

Comment: What you have in the paint event is what you'll get on the screen. You shouldn't expect anything else. You can see the base class implementation in the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/staging/source/4377e247e135967eb7b4c89906415abecb283bd3:src/gui/widgets/qpushbutton.cpp#L449).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the docs [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-stylable-widgets), you will need to add this into your paint event:

```
 void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
 {
     QStyleOption opt;
     opt.init(this);
     QPainter p(this);
     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);

     //your other code here
 }
```

Comment: still doesnt work. I tried following  QPushButton::paintEvent(e);

    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
    p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    p.drawEllipse(0, 0, 50, 50);   this sets icon but not as circular and shape of Qpushbutton also changes to normal

Comment: Set border-radius in stylesheet as "border-radius:10px;"